# Use <TAB> to intent text in nxhtml-mode PHP buffer

Tags: php, emacs, key-bindings, nxhtml

I use `nxhtml` for web-development. So far I was pretty satisfied with default settings, but this one freaks me out. I use CI a lot, and when I have to edit language files, I'd like to keep them tidy:

```
$lang['foo_one']                 = 'First option';
$lang['foo_two']                 = 'Second option';
$lang['foo_three']<TAB>
```

Sadly, with default `TAB` behaviour, I can't place new array item in a correct position. `TAB` just does nothing. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`align-regexp` can do this for you, but you have to run it manually.

this is the second voted single [most useful emacs feature](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60367/the-single-most-useful-emacs-feature/60537#60537)